# this keyword acts different between NodeJS and Vanila JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lexical-scope

I'm trying to learn about JavaScript lexical scoping and closures. I ran this example using Node.js and then in the browser and got 2 different outputs.

tested on `chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
and `Node v12.16.1`

```js
var obj1 = {
        name: "Pulsar",
        bike: function() {
          console.log(this.name);
        }
      }
      var obj2 = { name: "Gixxer", bike: obj1.bike };
      var name = "Ninja";
      var bike = obj1.bike;
      
      bike();           // "Ninja"
      obj1.bike();      // "Pulsar"
      obj2.bike();      // "Gixxer"
```

This snippet of code acts differently in `Vanilla JavaScript`. The output is:

```
Ninja 
Pulser
Gixxer
```

and in `NodeJS` the output is:

```
undefined
Pulsar
Gixxer
```

can someone please explain?

Comment: Here's why it is different on both environments https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a browser, the `window` object is the global `this` object and all variables get assigned as its property. In node, there is no such object. There is a `this` ( `{}` ), `globalThis` and `module`, but the module variables do not get assigned to them, instead they are assigned in memory.

Answer (score 3):

In browsers the top-level scope is the global scope. It means that when you define something with `var` it becomes a property of the global object, which is `window`.

So `bike` and `name` are both defined in a global scope, which means they both are `window` properties, so `this` points to the `window` and it has a `name` property, with the value `Ninja`.

In node, any var in the global scope is defined in a different local module, so the `this` of the `bike` is not related to a `name` variable

Comment: To add to this, to make OP's code work, bike variable needs to use bind to an object with the name variable as property, like so: ```var bike = obj1.bike.bind({name});```